# Given Lebesgue measurable sets $X,Y,Z$, Show that $f(X,Z)\leq f(X,Y) + f(Y,Z)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

> Given any sigma algebra sets $X, Y$ and $Z$  and a function,
>   $f(X,Y):=\lambda((X-Y)\cup(Y-X))$ where $\lambda$ is a lebesgue
>   measure, show that $f(X,Z)\leq  f(X,Y) + f(Y,Z)$

So I have used the property that $f(X,Z)=\lambda((X-Z)\cup(Z-X))\leq \lambda(X-Z) + \lambda(Z-X)$, and similarly 
$f(X,Y) + f(Y,Z)\\=\lambda((X-Y)\cup(Y-X))+\lambda((Y-Z)\cup(Z-Y))\\\leq\lambda(X-Y) + \lambda(Y-X) +\lambda(Y-Z) + \lambda(Z-Y)$.

I then rearranged the right hand side to $\lambda(X-Y)+\lambda(Y-Z)+\lambda(Z-Y)+\lambda(Y-X)$.

I want to say that $\lambda(X-Y)+\lambda(Y-Z)=\lambda(X-Z) +\lambda(Z-X)$, but I know that is just nonsense. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Note that $S(X,Z):= (X-Z) \cup (Z-X) = (X - Y - Z) \cup ( (X \cap Y) - Z) \cup (Z - X).$ The first of the RHS terns is contained in $(X- Y),$ while the second is contained in $(Y - Z)$. Expand the last term in the same way to show that the original set is a subset of $S(X,Y) \cup S(Y,Z)$, and use subadditivity of measure.

Comment: @stochasticboy321What does $S(X,Z)$ stand for? and How does it have $Y$ in the expansion?

Comment: I defined it in the very first expression (look for the $:=$). All I'm using above is that for any sets $A$ and $B, A = (A \cap B) \cup (A - B).$ This allows you to decompose $X$ as $(X \cap Y) \cup (X - Y).$

Comment: @stochasticboy321I proved it! Thank you! :)